# Variable locator using playwright

Tags: javascript, button, playwright

I want to use a locator in Playwright, but I need to use the locator to click on a button that should change my "for". I need to click a button, collect data, click another button, and collect the same data...
My code:

```
for (let i = 0;i < data.listTeamOne.length; i++) {
        let a = "xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div["i+1"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div"
        await page.locator(a).click()
```

but that syntax does not work
Does someone have any ideas to help?

```
for (let i = 0;i < data.listTeamOne.length; i++) {
        let a = "xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div["i+1"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div"
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Brian Mederios, welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The shared xpath is disastrous, one should NEVER use an XPath like that.Its so brittle and will break on the slightest change on the page UI.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the way you are creating the locator string `a` that is the problem. Using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should fix it:

```js
let a = `xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div${String(i+1)}]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div`
```